# With Crossfilter how do I return an array of all the id values for a specific type

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

Forgive me, I'm not sure I'm approaching this problem correctly.

I have some data (many thousands of elements) with a type and an ID:

```
const data = [
  { type: 'foo', id: 1 },
  { type: 'foo', id: 3 },
  { type: 'foo', id: 5 },
  { type: 'baz', id: 8 },
  { type: 'baz', id: 10 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 11 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 13 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 17 },
  ...
];
```

With [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/), I want to filter by a type and return an array of all their ids.

For example: all the type 'bar' should return `[10, 11, 13, 17]`

My attempt was to group reduce. But I didn't get very far with it:

```
let ndx = crossfilter(data);
let d = ndx.dimension(d => d.type);
let reduceAdd = (p, v) => p.push(v);
let reduceRemove = (p, v) => p.filter(i => i !== v);
let reduceInitial = () => ([]);
```

And then something like:

```
d.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial)
```

Comment: please add your attempt.

Comment: Someone took crossfilter out of the title.

Comment: This happens a lot when you use the `javascript` tag. People will also tend to give you answers in pure Javascript rather than answers explaining how to use the Crossfilter library, which is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method in combination with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [*destructing assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const data = [ { type: 'foo', id: 1 }, { type: 'foo', id: 3 }, { type: 'foo', id: 5 }, { type: 'baz', id: 8 }, { type: 'baz', id: 10 }, { type: 'bar', id: 11 }, { type: 'bar', id: 13 }, { type: 'bar', id: 17 }, ], type = 'bar';
console.log(data.filter(elem => elem.type == type).map(({id}) => id));
```

Comment: If the destructing assignment is foreign to you or you simply don't want to use it you could replace it with a better understandable `elem => elem.id`.

Answer (score 3):

What you've got looks pretty much correct with me. You just have to query your group by saving it to a variable

`var grp = d.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial)`

and then query it like

`grp.top(Infinity)`

This will return an array of objects. The key of one of the objects will be `bar` and the value of that object will be the array of records where `type` is `bar`.

Comment: It's just a variable name. I've seen it used a lot in dc.js examples for the main crossfilter object. I'm not sure why.

Comment: The reason isn't good - it was copied from the stock index example that's on the main page. (I try to use `cf` going forward.)

Comment: @Rimian Please make sure to accept the answer if it was correct. It helps raise the Crossfilter answer to Crossfilter questions to the top of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single `forEach()` is more efficient in this case instead of using `filter()` and then `map()` because you have complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the number of objects but using `filter()` and then `map()` there will be complexity of `O(n+m)` where `m` is the number of filtered records on which you do `map()`:

```js
const data = [
  { type: 'foo', id: 1 },
  { type: 'foo', id: 3 },
  { type: 'foo', id: 5 },
  { type: 'baz', id: 8 },
  { type: 'baz', id: 10 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 11 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 13 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 17 },
];
let type = 'bar';
var res = [];
data.forEach((obj)=> {
  if(obj.type===type){
    res.push(obj.id);
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

If there are `8` objects then you are iterating `8` times in filter and then lets say you get `4` records in filter you will then iterate `4` times to get the `id` value in the resultant array. Total of `12` iterations. So, in such cases I prefer to support the usage of `forEach()` in which there will be only `8` iterations to get the same set of array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { type: 'foo', id: 1 },
  { type: 'foo', id: 3 },
  { type: 'foo', id: 5 },
  { type: 'baz', id: 8 },
  { type: 'baz', id: 10 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 11 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 13 },
  { type: 'bar', id: 17 },
];
let type =  'bar';
let result = data.reduce((acc, {type, id})=>{
   if(!acc[type]) acc[type]=[];
   acc[type].push(id);
   return acc
},{})

console.log(result[type]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.reduce` here.

```js
const data = [
    { type: 'foo', id: 1 },
    { type: 'foo', id: 3 },
    { type: 'foo', id: 5 },
    { type: 'baz', id: 8 },
    { type: 'baz', id: 10 },
    { type: 'bar', id: 11 },
    { type: 'bar', id: 13 },
    { type: 'bar', id: 17 }
];

const filteredArray = data.reduce((result, obj) => {
  if (obj.type === "bar") {
    result.push(obj.id)
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(filteredArray)
```